# Disable iMessage in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an iPhone app that requires MFMessageComposeViewController to send texts as actual texts and not as iMessage. Is there a way to protect the texts from being sent as iMessage?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?  Why would you try and break my messaging experience?  If I don't have a SMS plan on my phone, this requirement would *cost me money*.

Comment: The app is about text-messaging. Mainly delivery reporting. You don't need delivery reporting for iMessage, as it's already developed by Apple.

Comment: @DaveDeLong: But it is possible users are aware of costing before sending. Message sending will be failed if iMessage not available on the other hand. Implementing `MFMessageComposeViewController`in app will not serve purpose as user will only come to know failed message delivery when he/she goes to messages and notices otherwise they will be under impression that SMS is delivered (let's assume they really want to send SMS.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. iOS controls the routing and there's no way to impact it. (Even from Messages you can't control this.)

Comment: Is it then posible to receive a message from MFMessageComposeViewController, if the iMessage was delivered correctly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure not. You can check if it's possible to send texts, but you can't tell if they were sent or not (because the phone was unable to send them or because the user canceled.) I believe Apple would consider this a privacy issues. There are alternative ways to send texts via web services, etc., but that's a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: Thanks! Then I have to write a note to the users, not to use iMessage :-)